# how to subscribe to observable whose input depends on data from other observable

Tags: angular, observable

In my Angular app I have a component whose data depends on a route parameter. 
When the page opens the first time the data is loaded correctly. When I change to a different page but stay on the same component (so only one route parameters change) the new data is not loaded.

the routeparameters are updated and all the data that is being subscribed to with the async pipe is loaded correctly. there is however one piece of data that needs extra handling. this observable is being subscribed to in the component. this is the one with data that isnt loaded again.

In the code below the build-in paramMap observable subscription keeps on tracking changes to the route parameters and running the callback. the second observable doesnt. I suppose this is because the second observable is completed and is actually replaced by a new one which is never subscribed to (in the fist callback).

how to best handle this problem to also get the data from the second observable?

The only thing that seems to make it work is to move this second subscription to the callback of the first. but that doesnt look to very clean code to me and I'm not certain what would happen if for some reason the observable doesnt complete by the time it is replaced by the new one.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.parent.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap: ParamMap) => {
    this.id = paramMap.get('id');
    this.observable= this.service.getSomething(this.id);
  }
  this.observable.subscribe(
    // callback that handles the processing of the data
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use operators :

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.observable = this.route.parent.paramMap.pipe(
    map(paramMap => paramMap.get('id')),
    switchMap(id => this.service.getSomething(id))
  );
}
```

`switchMap` will cancel pending requests.

If you want to keep them active, use `mergeMap`.

Comment: this is the exact solution I was working on before posting my question but I couldnt get it working (new to observables and rxjs in general) because the example I found was using the old style of using the operators. I am still wondering how to correctly unsubscribe. if the observable completes it isnt necessary, but if doesnt when to unsubscribe?

Comment: @YoNuevo you can unsubscribe when you want to, what I find the most convenient is to use the `async` pipe in the template. I rarely write a `.subscribe` in my component code.

Comment: using the async pipe would solve the unsubscribing issue but unfortunately isnt possible for this subscription (unlike the several others used in this component). in most (if not all) cases unsubscribing isnt necessary because the observable will complete. but if it doesnt and then route parameter changes, the getSomething is ran again and a new observable is created. will the old one keep floating around somewhere or does the cancelling of the switchMap take care of this?

Comment: No, the subsription to the route will stay. Either use flow-stopping operators if you know how many times you will listen (`first`, `take(1)`, etc.), or unsubscribe in your `ngOnDestroy` function.

Comment: I explained (or understood) poorly :) I'm not worried about the subscription to the route but about the observable returned from getSomething. it is very unlikely but not impossible that the route parameter will change before it completes. if this happens and the code in switchMap gets excuted again, wont a new observable be returned from getSomething? What happens to the original one? does it get cancelled and unsubscribed automatically by the switchMap operator or should I do it manually

Comment: Well I'll be clear : the route is hot, the HTTP call is cold. Hot observables keep listening, cold observables are closed when done. `switchMap` will cancel the cold observable **if not finished**, `mergeMap` will **let the previous observable finish**. This means that in my code, the request is cancelled, the original one stops (so no `subscribe` triggered), and since it's cold, you don't need to unsubscribe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188354/discussion-between-yonuevo-and-trichetriche).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `switchMap` operator form RxJS here like:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.parent.paramMap.pipe(switchMap((paramMap: ParamMap) => {
      this.id = paramMap.get('id');
      return this.service.getSomething(this.id);
    })).subscribe(
        // callback that handles the processing of the data
      );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could imagine that you want to do something like below (rxjs v6):

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.parent.paramMap.pipe(
      map(paramMap: ParamMap) => this.id = paramMap.get('id'),
      mergeMap(id => this.service.getSomething(this.id))
    )
      .subscribe(
        // callback that handles the processing of the data
      )
  }
```

so whenever the params changes the whole pipe gets triggered and the service gets called.